# Allow input of all types of video files

Tags: html, reactjs, web, input

Currenty my website doesn't allow input of .avi, .wmv etc. files and doesn't process it.

The code looks like this -

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="previewVideo"
  style={{ width: 0, height: 0, display: "none" }}
  accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"
/>
```

I want it to accept all types of video files. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I use a library called `video-metadata-thumbnails` and a function from that library called `getThumbnails` to display the thumbnail of the video uploaded.
It seems that this library doesn't parse all types of video files like .avi, .wmv etc.

```
                          <input
                            type="file"
                            id="previewVideo"
                            style={{ width: 0, height: 0, display: "none" }}
                            accept="video/*"
                            onChange={async (e) => {
                              this._uploadPreviewVideo(e.target.files[0]);
                              const videoFile = e.target.files[0];
                              if (e.target) e.target.value = "";
                              let thumbnails = [];
                              try {
                                thumbnails = await getThumbnails(
                                  URL.createObjectURL(videoFile),
                                  {
                                    quality: 0.6,
                                    start: 3,
                                    end: 5,
                                  }
                                );
                                this.setState({
                                  previewVideo: thumbnails[0].blob,
                                });
                              } catch (error) {
                                console.log("Video Upload Error: ", error);
                              }
                              
                            }}
                          />
```

What should I do to display thumbnails for such video formats? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try just `accept="video/*"`

Comment: Already tried.doesn't work